# codeigniter file upload, submitting to database twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

So im having a really strange problem. i have a form that collects some user details and their profile pic. All works as it should, sort of.

i want to be able to have a default image for the user if they do not upload a picture. with the code below if they do not upload a picture everything is fine and all the details and default image get saved into the database.

but here is where it gets strange, if you do upload a pic it inserts the details into the database twice. once with the uploaded pic and then again with the default pic. For the life of me i can not figure it out i have spent hours messing around with it. any help is appreciated.

Controller :

```
function addNewStaff()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin() == TRUE) {
        $this->loadThis();
    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roleId', 'Role Id', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required|min_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Start Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contract_type', 'Contract Type', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->addNewStaff_View();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something Went Wrong');
        } else {                                         

            $first_name = ucwords(strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('first_name'))));
            $last_name = ucwords(strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('last_name'))));
            $roleId = $this->input->post('roleId');
            $email = strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email')));
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $mobile = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('mobile'));
            $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
            $contract_type = $this->input->post('contract_type');

            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start_date);
            $formatteddate = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
                                        
             
            if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

                // Set preference
                $config['upload_path'] = 'content/uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = '1024'; // max_size in kb
                $config['file_name'] = $first_name . $last_name . $date = date('Y-m-d');
           
                //Load upload library
                $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
           
                // File upload
                if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                  // Get data about the file
                  $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                  $profile_picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
                  
                }                   
              }                 
            else{
                $profile_picture = 'default.png';
            }     
              
            $staffInfo = array(
                'email' => $email, 'password' => getHashedPassword($password), 'roleId' => $roleId, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name,
                'mobile' => $mobile, 'start_date' => $formatteddate, 'contract_type' => $contract_type, 'profile_pic'=> $profile_picture
            );

            $result = $this->staff_model->addNewStaff($staffInfo);

            if ($result > 0) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Staff member added successfully');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'staff member creation failed');
            }

            redirect('staffList');
        }
    }
}
```

Model :

```
function addNewStaff($staffInfo)
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('tbl_staff', $staffInfo); 
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return TRUE;       
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Controller Code:-**

```
function addNewStaff()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin() == TRUE) {
        $this->loadThis();
    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roleId', 'Role Id', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[128]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required|min_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Start Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contract_type', 'Contract Type', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->addNewStaff_View();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something Went Wrong');
        } else {                                         

            $first_name = ucwords(strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('first_name'))));
            $last_name = ucwords(strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('last_name'))));
            $roleId = $this->input->post('roleId');
            $email = strtolower($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email')));
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $mobile = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('mobile'));
            $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
            $contract_type = $this->input->post('contract_type');

            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start_date);
            $formatteddate = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
                                        
             
            if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

                // Set preference
                $config['upload_path'] = 'content/uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = '1024'; // max_size in kb
                $config['file_name'] = $first_name . $last_name . $date = date('Y-m-d');
           
                //Load upload library
                $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
           
                // File upload
                if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                  // Get data about the file
                  $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                  $profile_picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
                  
                }                   
                               
            else{
                $profile_picture = 'default.png';
            }     
           }          
            $staffInfo = array(
                'email' => $email, 'password' => getHashedPassword($password), 'roleId' => $roleId, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name,
                'mobile' => $mobile, 'start_date' => $formatteddate, 'contract_type' => $contract_type, 'profile_pic'=> $profile_picture
            );

            $result = $this->staff_model->addNewStaff($staffInfo);

            if ($result > 0) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Staff member added successfully');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'staff member creation failed');
            }

            redirect('staffList');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is any different here?